# Drupal users syncs with Gmail

Tags: drupal, gmail, contacts, google-apps, google-contacts-api

I'm using Drupal 6 and I want to sync it with Google contacts of one email account I own. Is this possible? I just want that when people sign up to the mailing list from my Drupal site, that email somehow will be saved in my google contacts or email group of my gmail account/ google apps account so I can send send emails to that group of contacts or group of emails.

Am I being clear enough?
Thanks in advanced.

Best,

Alex.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Google Contact API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/)

Comment: +1 Good idea, better than mine. (Sorry - initially downvoted this after thinking it was a reply to a different question.)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of would be LDAP. However, Google Apps only offers a one-way sync - i.e. it creates/deletes Google Apps accounts based on what's on your LDAP server, but you can't use Google Apps itself as an LDAP server.

The workaround would therefore be using another server as the LDAP server, and managing both Google Apps accounts and Drupal accounts from there.

Here's a good walkthrough on [setting up Drupal with LDAP](http://webschuur.com/publications/blogs/2007-02-17-howto_turn_drupal_into_an_authenticate_only_site_with_users_from_an_ldap_directory).